# change TLS without changing the application server properties

Tags: java

just like the title suggests, I am currently working on a sub-project of an enterprise application needing to change the `TLS` version in my project. Remember that my project is one of many projects running on the application server, So changing the `System properties` would change the property for all the projects running on that application server. So I would be appreciated if you could show me the way to `change TLS version without changing the system`.
Thanks in advance